# Why does <h1> have a line-break?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a template for headlines that later on will have varying length. Before the headline is an icon. Why does the headline break, according to the icon width?

[js **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/)

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.ecotricity.ch/pix/slideBanner/carLogo.gif" width="50"/>
<div> 
   <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1241/twitter_land/256/school_of_fish.png" width="50"/> 
   <h3> The cars are faster than fish</h3> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{ 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

img{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You can set the width of the div to 100% to have the text and the icon in the same line.

Comment: Floating elements are removed from the normal flow and don't change the width/height of their parent container. It would be a good idea to read up about what certain properties do before using them.

Comment: Is this what you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not clearing the float after the `img` element within the `div`.

You have two options. You can either use CSS to remove the `float` from that `img` element:

```css
div img {
    float: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/1/).

Or add a clearing element within your `div`:

```
<img src="..." width="50"/> 
<br style="clear:both"/>
<h3> The cars are faster than fish</h3>
```

[**JSFiddle demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/2/).

If you want the `h3` element to be alongside the `img` element, you can alter option 1 above to:

```css
div img,
div h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/6/).

Comment: Your first two options don't answer the actual question, only the last one does.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your div style with:

```
div{ 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width:300px;
}
//increase the width of div
```

Comment: Setting a fixed width isn't a good solution as it would require the site maintainer to constantly update the styling if the content changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Why does H1 have a line break" the answer is because it is a block level element; however, if you are asking how to accomplish something like having all the elements in a vertical line, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/rM6G9/7/

```
div{ 
    float: left;
    clear:both;
}

img{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
h3{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

If you want the second image and the headline to be inline do this:

```
div{ 
    float: left;
    clear:both;
}

img{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
h3{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the actual question, having all the elements in a _vertical_ line is what you get when you add no styling at all.